# Copying column(s) after groupby and then finding out time delta

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Two parter but related. I have a dataframe df1 of this form

```
a  b  c  date1  date2
a1 b1 c1 date11 date21
a1 b2 c2 date12 date22
a1 b2 c3 date13 date23
```

First Question: I want to get another multiple index dataframe grouped by a and b and displaying date1 (shifted) and date2. 
Like so

```
a  b  date1_shifted  date2
a1 b1 NaN            date21
   b2 date13         date22
      NaN            date23
```

There has got to be a better way but this is what I did

```
date1_shifted = df1.groupby(['a', 'b']).agg({'date1':lambda x: x})
df = date1_shifted.groupby(level=[0,1]).shift(-1)
df.rename(columns={'date1':'date1_shifted'}, inplace=True)
dummy = df1.groupby(['a','b']).agg({'date2':lambda x: x})
df=df.merge(dummy, left_index= True, right_index= True)
```

The above code does the job but it's....ugly. The big problem however is that the datetime datatype of date1_shifted and date2 changed from datetime to object.

Which brings up the second question - I want to have another column 'time_delta' which is the difference between date1_shifted and date2

```
df['time_delta']=df['date1_shifted']-df['date2]
```

Result

```
a  b  date1_shifted  date2   time_delta
a1 b1 NaN            date21  NaN
   b2 date13         date22  179000000000 nanoseconds
      NaN            date23  NaN
```

Note the 'nanoseconds' explicitly written. It is also an Object datatype and I'm having trouble using this column as a condition. For example:

```
df[df['time_delta']>30]
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat simpler:

```
df= df.set_index(['a','b'])
df["date1_shifted"]=df.date1.groupby(level=[0,1]).shift(-1)
df=df.reindex(columns=["date1_shifted","date2"])
df["time_delta"]= (pd.to_datetime(df.date1_shifted)-pd.to_datetime(df.date2)).astype("np.int64")
df=df.reset_index()
```